# iis hosting WCF Service

Tags: web-hosting, wcf-data-services, wcf-binding

I trying host my project, but when I run svc file then i get exception.
Exception data: System.InvalidOperationException: The convention requires the use of Session, but the "BasicHttpBinding" binding is not supported or is not configured correctly.
What could be the problem?

I tried changing the web.config file but I don't know what the problem is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your binding mode from BasicHttpBinding to WsHttpBinding. Since the default binding method for HTTP is BasicHttpBinding, you can modify it in the **<System.ServiceModel>**:

```
<protocolMapping>
<add scheme="http" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WsHttpSession"/>
</protocolMapping>
```

This allows you to modify the binding.